# Como convertir a escala de gris con OPENCV y java en Android studio

Tags: java, android

Como puedo convertir a escala de gris de un imagview1 y mostrar la conversión en otro imagview2; pero quiero mantener la imagen original del imagview1; el siguiente código me convierte, pero me lo muestra en el mismo imagview1(le cambia el color) y en el imagview2(esta correcto); en conclusión quiero mantener la imagen del imagview1 a color (original) :

```
public void EscalaGrisOPENCV(){
  BitmapDrawable drawable =(BitmapDrawable) imagview1.getDrawable();
  Bitmap bitfoto= drawable.getBitmap();

  Mat tmp = new Mat (bitfoto.getWidth(), bitfoto.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
  Utils.bitmapToMat(bitfoto, tmp);
  Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY );

  Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA, 4);
  Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bitfoto);

  imagview2.setImageBitmap(bitfoto);
}
```

Comment: Simplemente copia el `ImageView1` en el `ImageVIew2` y conviértelo ahí.

Comment: De que forma, puedes darme un ejemplo, estoy bloqueado

Comment: Create un bitmap aparte y pasale eso al final en matToBitmap en ves de la original dale otra o una copia de el. Bitmap tiene la funcion copy creo